# wait for page load for non-angular Application using protractor

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor

i am new to protractor and testing Non-Angular login Page and on clicking login button on login page a new page appears and i need to click on a planning link.But on clicking Login button application takes around 50 seconds.I want the protractor to wait untill the planning link appears.I used browser.wait(),browser.driver.implicitltyWait() but no success. I am able to click on planning link using browser.sleep() only.
Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for any WebElement in the page that is loaded after you perform login operation.

> var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
>
> browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id("someId"))),60000)

it will wait for the element and throw exception after waiting for 1 minute

Comment: it is not working :( na dthrows error:-- C:\Users\Pooja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium
-webdriver\lib\promise.js:654
    throw error;
    ^
 Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "root element (html)
has no injector. this may mean it is not inside ng-app.".DO i need to make some changes in my config.js??

Comment: i am wriiting my code in a js file and that js file is being called in the single spec i have in my project.i have a function named login to login the application and after that i want the protractor to wait for around 50 seconds to click planning link(non-angular)

Comment: Try using `browser.IgnoreSynchronization = true;` at the beginning of your test.

Comment: already done,using this property before browser.get(),even before passing username,password at login page and before clicking planning link,but same issue occurs all the time

Answer (score 0):

So what I understood from your question is that you have a non angular login page and click on login button takes you to another page(Is this angular or non angular?) which takes around 50 sec to load and contains a link(planning). Right?? And clicking on that link will take you to your angular home page.

And the issue which you are facing now is that the protractor is not waiting 50sec for the page containing the planning link to load.

Please try this and let me know the result..

```
this.clickLoginBtn = function () {
    browser.driver.findElement(loginBtn).click();
    return browser.wait(function () {
        return browser.driver.isElementPresent(planningLink);
    }, 50000);
};
```

I used browser.driver.findElement since we are on the non angular page.

Comment: yes on clicking login page app navigates to a page that is non-angular as well that contains the planning link.clicking on planning link page navigates to angular space. i have used the above said code but as it is not waiting for 50 secs when it tries to click planning link 
 
it is throwing exception : NoSuchElementError: no such element (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.241075,platform=Windows NT 6.2 x86_64)  beacuse  planning link is not appeared and page is loading

Answer (score 0):

I [wrote a blog post about this](http://qualityshepherd.com/2015/08/protractor-navigating-pages-without-angular/), and have working [examples on github](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor_example), specifically when testing non-Angular apps. It makes use of [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions), and [Page Objects](http://www.protractortest.org/#/#page-objects).

If you're not using Page Objects yet, you'd do something like:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'loginBtn' to be clickable.
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable($('#loginBtn')), 50000);
```

Comment: i am not using Page Objects and using the above code ,it does not wait for the application to load and throws error  i.e -----C:\Users\Pooja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium
-webdriver\lib\promise.js:654
    throw error;
    ^
 Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "root element (html)
has no injector. this may mean it is not inside ng-app."

Comment: That error indicates Protractor is looking for Angular's `ng-app`, but as you mention, your app is non-Angular. Have you set `ignoreSynchronization ` to true? Also, sorry, just checking... but you _did_ replace `$('#loginBtn')` with your actual input selector?